# How to group ggplot2 boxplots into heterogenous groups (not the usual grouping of boxplots)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Let's say I have 5 boxplots, for instance ozone levels in May to September.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                           labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))

plot <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, fill = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot()
plot
```

Now I want to visually group them into, for instance 2+1+2: So I want to have a gap between June and July as well as July and August. (The actual groupings might be different).

The usual approaches for grouping boxplots do not seem to cover this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a variable that groups your x variable—the method depends on your data, but `forcats::fct_collapse` is one easy way to do this. Then use that to facet the plots. With `facet_grid`, you can set a free x-scale and free spacing, so that the panels are sized based on how many boxplots they each have.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                           labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))

air_groups <- airquality %>%
  mutate(group = forcats::fct_collapse(Month, 
                              "group 1" = c("May", "Jun"),
                              "group 2" = c("Jul"),
                              "group 3" = c("Aug", "Sep")))
ggplot(air_groups, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, fill = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group), scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

[image]

If you want to disguise the fact that you're using facets, or the groups aren't actually meaningful on their own, you can remove the facet labels. There are other theme parameters that would be good to experiment with here, such as the spacing between the panels.

```r
ggplot(air_groups, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone, fill = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group), scales = "free_x", space = "free") +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
#> Warning: Removed 37 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the problem that I described very nicely. I am wondering if there is any way to have *two* levels of facets in the same direction (here x-axis). One for the solution you described (probably hiding the facet labels). One for actually distinguishing between two facets, e.g., to show other measurements to the right-hand side of the Ozone ones, then repeating May-Sep with other values.

Comment: I don't totally get what you mean about showing other measurements--like a different measure on your y-axis, not ozone? If you want two levels for facetting, you can add a second variable name in `vars`. AFAIK you can't remove just one level of strips but not the other—I had this problem a few days ago and created a set of dummy blank labels for the level I wanted unlabeled. Not a perfect solution though

Answer (score 1):

This might be cheating but I'm not quite sure how much you care about the labeling on your `x` axis.

```
library (dplyr) # for case_when()
special_x <- case_when(airquality$Month == "May" ~ 1,
              airquality$Month == "Jun" ~ 2,
              airquality$Month == "Jul" ~ 4,
              airquality$Month == "Aug" ~ 6,
              airquality$Month == "Sep" ~ 7)

    airquality$special_x <- special_x

    ggplot(airquality, aes(x = special_x, y = Ozone, fill = Month)) +
      geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Additionally, you can add `+ labs(x="") + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())`.

### UPDATE

As the comment says,

```
ggplot(airquality, aes(x = special_x, y = Ozone, fill = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,4,6,7),
                     labels =c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))+
  labs(x="")
```

Would produce

[image]

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(breaks =  c(1,2,4,6,7),  labels =c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))`